# Is there any way to load scripts in Wordpress asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I looked through the Wordpress documentation and couldn't find any mention of async javascript loading using wp_enqueue_script(), is it possible at all? I have a couple of scripts and would rather async load them to improve the user loading experience!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_enqueue_script()` to load a "script loader", which is a script that loads other scripts. That way, you are loading the bootloader synchronously, but the others asynchronously.

Your script-loader could contain this:

```
var scriptUrls = [URLS_HERE];

scriptUrls.forEach(function(url,index,scriptUrls){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  script.src = url;
});
```

Comment: I do do it that way (using wp_enqueue_script() and then loading the script loader function), but google speed test is telling me they are render-blocking scripts.

Comment: The script-loader itself is render-blocking, but if you take a moment to notice that it isn't that big. You can even embed that into the page. The rest of the scripts, which is the bulk of your JS, are loaded asynchronously and shouldn't be render-blocking.